# How to correctly insert a date in my database using Java with spring/hibernate (getting wrong hours in my db)?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, datetime, calendar

So recently I've been working with the Calendar and Date datatype in my project and having problems inserting (and retrieving) the correct amount of hours into (from) my database (using Spring and Hibernate/MySql5Dialect).

When I tried using a stored procedure in my spring application which would select some dates (DATETIME datatype) from the db, the object returned in Java always is one hour before the actual date in my db (for example, 2019-03-30 09:00:00 in my db and I get 2019-03-30 08:00:00 returned from my service). Now when I call the same procedure in mysql workbench, then it works perfectly.

Now I noticed when I tried inserting a record with a date inside it from my spring application, for example 2019-03-30 09:00:00, I get 2019-03-30 08:00:00 in my database, here is how I inserted the date:

```java
private PatientAppointmentDTOR createPatientAppointmentDTOR() {
        PatientAppointmentDTOR dtor = factory.manufacturePojo(PatientAppointmentDTOR.class);
        dtor.setCpId(5L); // foreign keys...
        dtor.setBranchId(2L);
        dtor.setPtId(32L);
        dtor.setEmployeeId(55L);
        dtor.setInDepartmentId(7L);
        dtor.setPatientAppointmentStatusId(20L);
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
        cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);
        cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Date start = cal1.getTime();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
        cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,30);
        cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Date end = cal2.getTime();
        dtor.setStartTime(start);
        dtor.setEndTime(end);
        Company company = companyService.getEntityById(5L);
        GroupDTOS gdtos = groupService.getDTOById(2L);
        when(auth.userDetails())
         .thenReturn(EntityFactory
         .createUserDetails(DBStaticFields.Role.CLINIC_ADMIN, company, gdtos, factory));
        return dtor;
    }
```

and then I just inserted this into my database using this JUnit test:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("test insertion")
    void testInsert() {
        PatientAppointmentDTOR dtor = this.createPatientAppointmentDTOR();
        PatientAppointmentDTOS dtos = patientAppointmentService.insert(dtor);
        assertThat(dtos).isNotNull();
        assertThat(dtos.getId()).isNotNull();
    }
```

So yeah, when I insert these values from my application, startDate is 2019-03-30 11:00:00 and endDate is 2019-03-30 11:30:00 in my database. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Check the timezone in both: your application + db server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As akuma8 pointed out, the problem was with the timezone set in my application properties. If someone has a similar problem, just set the correct timezone  "&serverTimezone=$$$" in your application properties where the connection to the database is made, now everything matches correctly.

Thanks akuma8!